# paint touchevent in android

Tags: android, touch-event, buttonclick

in my application,i want to get the position on touchevent.but when i click on button after that i want to call ontouchevent and onDraw() method and get the position.
how can i do this?Please help me

```
   public void getPos(View v){
      //here i want to call onTouchEvent method..
    }

     @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

       Log.d("position", event.getX() + "-" + event.getY());
        return true;
    }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Am I right, that you have an `android:onClick="getPos"` in your button's xml?

Comment: yes.but how can i call onTouchEvent and onDraw method on that button click????

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not call those methods by yourself. All methods named `on...` are callback methods that are called by the Android system when certain events happen. In your case this method (defined in the Activity) is called when there's a touch-event that's not handled elsewhere.
Touching the button *is* handled by the button, therefore the onTouchEvent of the Activity is not called.

What you could do, is to add an onTouchEventListener to your button:

So in your `onCreate()` method (another method called by Android at the event of the acitity beeing created), find your button and add the listener like so:

```
View button = findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            Log.d("position", event.getX() + "-" + event.getY());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note, that I always return `false` as to not to interfere with the button. If you return `true`, the event will be "eaten up" and not passed along to be handled by views anymore. So you may tweak this at will.
Btw. as you can see, you can attach an OnTouchListener to any view, so perhaps you don't need an actual button at all.

Comment: will it work??i think it will give buttons position.because after clicking on button getaction is called

Comment: It gives the position of the touch-event on the screen as that's what event.x and event.y contain. Why do you not simply try it?

Comment: its working..thanku so much..also after that i want to draw circle on that position.would it possible??

Comment: Glad I could help. As to drawing a circle -- you cannot easily paint directly on the button, but I suppose you could add a transparent custom View to your layout 'in front of' all the other layout and you can implement the onDraw() method of that view to paint the circle. A look at the SurfaceView documentation should help you I hope.

Comment: i want to draw circle on image which is in imageview.after drawing i want to save that image.

Comment: well, that are two more quite complex questions, so you should try to find answers in the internet (or even better the android developer documentation).

Answer (score 0):

Calling onTouchEvent manually will not do you any good, because **onTouchEvent** is a callback method used by android to deliver you touch events ( you can't call it and expect it to have touch data ready for you )

Instead what you can do is keep track of your touch events and when **getPos** gets called you read your latest touch event data. your code should look something like this:

```
private float lastX = -1;
private float lastY = -1;

public void getPos(View v){
  //here i want to call onTouchEvent method..
    if (lastX == -1 || lastY == -1) {
      // no touch events 
       return;
    }
    // do whatever you want with the x,y values
    //reset them for the next check
    lastX = -1;
    lastY = -1;
}

    @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      lastX = event.getX();
      lastY = event.getY();
      Log.d("position", event.getX() + "-" + event.getY());
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: did you register for touch event listening ? 

View.setOnTouchListener(this); ?

Comment: Please add your activity code so we can tell you where exactely